# Date Time Picker not running in Adobe AIR

Tags: jquery, html, air, datetimepicker

I build application using html, jquery and adobe air. In part of my application, i use date time picker that provided by jquery. If i test them using browser , it works well. But when i combined with Adobe AIR, and compile it using AIR, it didn't work....

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Icon trigger</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/AIRAliases.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demos.css">

    <script language="JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

</div><!-- End demo -->



<div class="demo-description">
<p>Click the icon next to the input field to show the datepicker.  Set the datepicker to open on focus (default behavior), on icon click, or both.</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->

</body>
</html>
```

can anybody fix it? Thanks before

Comment: You're missing the `type`-attribute on your script. Second, have you tried isolating the error? Does `$().ready()` work, does a clean datepicker work, do other plugins work?

Comment: I have changed as your advice.. but it seem still like before.. when i run it, the date picker is shown , but if i click one of date button ..it didn't work.. any your suggestion?

Comment: check your consol any error message

Comment: @gowri i didn't find an error. when i clicked a number in datetime picker, it didn't work...:(

Answer (score 1):

As stated in this [post](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-ui-dev/browse_thread/thread/35a5fe4eaf1d6351) in the jQuery UI Development Group the jQuery datepicker in it's current form does not work in Adobe Air.
This is reported in [Bug #3945](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3945).
The reason is Datepickers use of dynamically created `onclick` events for the created Datepicker interface, such actions are not allowed within Adobe Air along with `eval()` and `setTimeout()`.
There is a revision in the works and some individuals have branched the main code to attempt a fix, these are documented on the links above.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by AppSol it is a problem with jQuery UI and AIR's sand-boxing. However it is quite easy to make a work-around. Just download not minified version of jQuery UI and add following to the end of _updateDatepicker() function. In version 1.8.16 its' on line 8954

```
$(".ui-datepicker-prev").click(function() {
            $.datepicker._curInst.drawMonth--;
            if ($.datepicker._curInst.drawMonth < 0) {
                $.datepicker._curInst.drawMonth = 11;
                $.datepicker._curInst.drawYear--;
            }
            $.datepicker._updateDatepicker($.datepicker._curInst);
        }); 

        $(".ui-datepicker-next").click(function() {
            $.datepicker._curInst.drawMonth++;
            if ($.datepicker._curInst.drawMonth > 11) {
                $.datepicker._curInst.drawMonth = 0;
                $.datepicker._curInst.drawYear++;
            }
            $.datepicker._updateDatepicker($.datepicker._curInst);
        }); 

        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").find("tr > td").each(function() {
            $(this).click(function() {
                var t = $(this).attr('onclick').split('.')[2].split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
                $.datepicker._selectDay(t[0].substr(1,t[0].length-2),t[1],t[2],this);
            });
        });
```

Here's how it should look like at the end:

```
/* Generate the date picker content. */
_updateDatepicker: function(inst) {
    var self = this;
    self.maxRows = 4; //Reset the max number of rows being displayed (see #7043)
    var borders = $.datepicker._getBorders(inst.dpDiv);
    instActive = inst; // for delegate hover events
    inst.dpDiv.empty().append(this._generateHTML(inst));
    var cover = inst.dpDiv.find('iframe.ui-datepicker-cover'); // IE6- only
    if( !!cover.length ){ //avoid call to outerXXXX() when not in IE6
        cover.css({left: -borders[0], top: -borders[1], width: inst.dpDiv.outerWidth(), height: inst.dpDiv.outerHeight()})
    }
    inst.dpDiv.find('.' + this._dayOverClass + ' a').mouseover();
    var numMonths = this._getNumberOfMonths(inst);
    var cols = numMonths[1];
    var width = 17;
    inst.dpDiv.removeClass('ui-datepicker-multi-2 ui-datepicker-multi-3 ui-datepicker-multi-4').width('');
    if (cols > 1)
        inst.dpDiv.addClass('ui-datepicker-multi-' + cols).css('width', (width * cols) + 'em');
    inst.dpDiv[(numMonths[0] != 1 || numMonths[1] != 1 ? 'add' : 'remove') +
        'Class']('ui-datepicker-multi');
    inst.dpDiv[(this._get(inst, 'isRTL') ? 'add' : 'remove') +
        'Class']('ui-datepicker-rtl');
    if (inst == $.datepicker._curInst && $.datepicker._datepickerShowing && inst.input &&
            // #6694 - don't focus the input if it's already focused
            // this breaks the change event in IE
            inst.input.is(':visible') && !inst.input.is(':disabled') && inst.input[0] != document.activeElement)
        inst.input.focus();
    // deffered render of the years select (to avoid flashes on Firefox) 
    if( inst.yearshtml ){
        var origyearshtml = inst.yearshtml;
        setTimeout(function(){
            //assure that inst.yearshtml didn't change.
            if( origyearshtml === inst.yearshtml && inst.yearshtml ){
                inst.dpDiv.find('select.ui-datepicker-year:first').replaceWith(inst.yearshtml);
            }
            origyearshtml = inst.yearshtml = null;
        }, 0);
    }
    $(".ui-datepicker-prev").click(function() {
        $.datepicker._curInst.drawMonth--;
        if ($.datepicker._curInst.drawMonth < 0) {
            $.datepicker._curInst.drawMonth = 11;
            $.datepicker._curInst.drawYear--;
        }
        $.datepicker._updateDatepicker($.datepicker._curInst);
    }); 

    $(".ui-datepicker-next").click(function() {
        $.datepicker._curInst.drawMonth++;
        if ($.datepicker._curInst.drawMonth > 11) {
            $.datepicker._curInst.drawMonth = 0;
            $.datepicker._curInst.drawYear++;
        }
        $.datepicker._updateDatepicker($.datepicker._curInst);
    }); 

    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").find("tr > td").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            var t = $(this).attr('onclick').split('.')[2].split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
            $.datepicker._selectDay(t[0].substr(1,t[0].length-2),t[1],t[2],this);
        });
    });

},
```

This was tested only in jQuery UI 1.8.16 however idea for fixing this in future versions will still stay the same. You will need to add click event handlers to next and prev buttons as well as actual dates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functional version of datepicker on Adobe Air:

> https://github.com/metaweta/jquery-ui/blob/df77b43f08c593ed5a21323c02cc51b8ada37b02/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js

Just use this file and the jquery.ui.core.js